# Having difficulty with model selection from a real data set

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I am having some issues trying to find the best models to explain some data.

I have a large set of data, containing more then 20 predictors, and a response variable, some of the predictors are factors, some are continuous, the response is continuous.

The sample size is very large ( several thousand).

My goal is to use R and methods of regression to come to some conclusions of what the best model would be.

I am not sure the best ways to do this, at first, I have been trying to brute force look at the predictors, but I am also interested in possibly using stepAIC or some variant of that to help.

More information: The data is from the NHANES health and nutrional study, which can be recieved in R by install.packages('NHANES') , library(NHANES).

What I am focusing on is a subset of this data, all from the 2011-12 year, on 21 seperate variables,

How I began:

I started off by fitting the model that included all predictors as a main effect, through R and use of drop1, this allowed me to drop the main effects of 7 predictors.

Also using R , I was able to conclude that the model with these predictors removed was an adequate simplification.

Now I decided I could maybe begin to look at first order interactions,

through R I eventually came up with the first order interactions deemed relevant, I added these into the model that included the relevant main effects.
( I only looked at interactions between factor predictors with continuous predictors, does it make sense to also look at interactions between factor and factor /continuous and continuous?)

Eventually, I get a model with $R^2=0.354$ , which is as high as I had managed to get it so far. ( without interactions it was in the 0.2 range)

However, $0.354$ still seems quite low to me, so I thought maybe I would need to include higher order interactions, but by this point I am very confused on where to begin because there are so many different possible combinations. So I am thinking that there must be a more simple way I can go about this model selection.

In regard to stepAIC, I am unsure how to interpret it. For example, I can try it with the model that uses say $x1$ as a factor and test $y~x1*(x3+...+)$ but how do I know that this is preferred over say $x2$ as a factor and test $y~x2*(x3+...)$?

Also what R commands can I use to see comparisons of things like BIC and mallow CP?

So I am looking for any and all help/advice on this topic.

Comment: Did you hold out data?  Are those $R^2$ statistics from the training data?

Comment: Sorry can you explain what you mean by hold out data and training data?

Comment: Training data is the data you use to fit the model.  In cases where you have a moderate to a large amount of data, you should not use *all* the available data to fit your model.  Data you do *not* use to fit your model is called hold out data, and it can be used to measure the performance of your model.  This is important in your case, because you are trying lots of things, and your training set model performance is quickly going to become overly optimistic.

Comment: I added some on edit, yes I am not using all the data

Comment: Ok, so are the $R^2$ statistics measured on data you did not use to train your model?

Comment: The only data I have is the subset data, so maybe I worded it wrong in saying I am not using all the data. I am using all the data that I have, however the study contains more predictors and years that I am not using.  My R^2 is based on what I do have to predict one of the variables, blood pressure, so in that sense maybe I am missing important predictors involved in blood pressure which maybe could explain the low R^2